# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to provide accessibility support

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, accessibility, worklight-runtime

we are working on a hybrid application targeting iOS and Android using IBM Worklight 6.1 - Developer Edition. We have to support accessibility. Any pointers, how to support it in hybrid applications, like what attributes to add, any libraries to add, or any inbuilt api that can be used, etc. I know how to provide accessibility support for native apps but am pretty new in hybrid front.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're talking about is accessibility in a Web environment. The way it is done for the Web should be mostly done in the Hybrid as well app with adjustments.

So I would google for accessibility in HTML5, for example:

- https://www.google.co.il/search?q=html5+accessibility&oq=html5+accessibility&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3895j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

There is also a topic about Accessibility in the IBM Worklight Information Center:

- [Developing accessible applications](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_developing_accessible_wl_applications.html)